# Getting error in countdown timer using react-countdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, countdown

I am currently building a countdown timer where a user inputs the time in minutes and can start and stop the clock. I am facing two errors,

1. I have made a state `running` when the clock is running and based on this state I am returning the buttons (either stop/ start), but I am getting the following error while using this function.

   `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render.`
2. The `autostart` prop of the `react-Countdown` component is not working in this case. ([link for doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown#autostart).

I have attached both codesandbox link and code also.

Here is the codesanbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-sound-rtd2c?file=/src/stopwatch.js:0-1400)

My current code is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Countdown from "react-countdown";

const Stopwatch = () => {
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(true);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(6);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setTime(e.target.value);
  };

  function buttons(running) {
   if(running ){
     return (
      <div>
        <button style={{ marginTop: "15px" }} onClick={() => setRunning(false)}>
          Stop
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  else {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setRunning(true)}>Start</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
  
  console.log("time = " + time);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="time"> Enter time in minutes </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="time"
          name="time"
          value={time}
          onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>
          <Countdown
            date={Date.now() + { time } * 4000}
            precision={3}
            autoStart={running}
            renderer={({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
              return (
                <span>
                  {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
                </span>
              );
            }}
          />
        </h1>
      </div>
      {buttons}
    </>
  );
};

export default Stopwatch;
```

Please tell the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the first error by using the function inside DOM only like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Countdown from "react-countdown";

const Stopwatch = () => {
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(6);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setTime(e.target.value);
  };


  console.log("time = " + time);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="time"> Enter time in minutes </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="time"
          name="time"
          value={time}
          onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>
          <Countdown
            date={Date.now() + { time } * 4000}
            precision={3}
            autoStart={running}
            renderer={({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
              return (
                <span>
                  {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
                </span>
              );
            }}
          />
        </h1>
      </div>
      {running ? (
        <div>
          <button
            style={{ marginTop: "15px" }}
            onClick={() => setRunning(false)}
          >
            Stop
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setRunning(true)}>Start</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Stopwatch;
```

But still, the `autostart` is not working, so after inputting the value in the text field and pressing start,  `the clock does not appear.`